# Поиск слова на странице

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Искала в интернете много примеров поиска слова по странице. Примеров мягко сказать не так уж и много..несколько из которых вообще не работоспособные.

Данный скрипт оказался рабочим. И я даже разобралась в нем. Однако хотела бы спросить как сделать чтобы допустим после совершения поиска если пользователь нажимал на кнопку мыши то все выделения исчезали? И второй моментик: как сделать переход по выделенным словам кнопками?

---

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     var lastResFind = ""; // последний удачный результат

     var copy_page = ""; // копия страницы в ихсодном виде

     function TrimStr(s) {

         s = s.replace(/^\s+/g, '');

         return s.replace(/\s+$/g, '');

     }
     function FindOnPage(inputId) {//ищет текст на странице, в параметр передается ID поля для ввода

         var obj = window.document.getElementById(inputId);

         var textToFind;

         if (obj) {
             textToFind = TrimStr(obj.value);//обрезаем пробелы
         } else {
             alert("Введенная фраза не найдена");
             return;
         }

         if (textToFind == "") {
             alert("Вы ничего не ввели");
             return;
         }
         if (textToFind.length < 2) {
             alert("Слишком короткий текст")
             return;
         }

         if (copy_page.length > 0)
             document.body.innerHTML = copy_page;

         else copy_page = document.body.innerHTML;

         document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/name=" + lastResFind + "/gi"), " ");//стираем предыдущие якори для скрола
         document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/" + textToFind + "/gi"), "<a name=" + textToFind + " style='background:yellow; font-size:15px'>" + textToFind + "</a>"); //Заменяем найденный текст ссылками с якорем;
         lastResFind = textToFind; // сохраняем фразу для поиска, чтобы в дальнейшем по ней стереть все ссылки
         window.location = '#' + textToFind;//перемещаем скрол к последнему найденному совпадению

     }

</script>
```

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить на счет библиотек..они работают аналогичным образом что меняют html код стиль слова который надо выделить или нет???

Comment: @Корделия способ выделения найденных слов в принципе везде одинаковый. Только стили разные.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь)Пробую разные варианты пытаясь найти для себя то что нужно. Так как вообще не понимаю javascript хотелось бы спросить еще один момента для организации перемещения скрола: возможно ли привязывать якорь не в ссылке тег <a> а допустим в элементе <span>. Где то видела что через id.Но что то не выходит.Может такое и нельзя делать?

Comment: @Корделия в принципе можно, но только с помощью js. На jQuery примерно так:

    $('span.anchor').on('click', function() {
        $(document).scrollTop(
            $('span[name='+$(this).attr()+']').scrollTop();
        );
    });

Comment: Для того чтобы работал scrollTop нужна jQuery определенная?:-)

Comment: @Корделия сори, перепутал scrollTop(), короче вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/k2YcF/1/

Comment: Долго не могла понять почему у меня не срабатывает пример предложенный Вами, даже реализовала его у себя. сработал он у меня только в Firefox. Возможно ли как нить доделать под другие браузеры?

Comment: @Корделия  видимо я что-то упустил про тег br. Переделал http://jsfiddle.net/k2YcF/2/

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает Window.find()?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function search(text) {
    // получаем текст
    var body =  document.getElementById('body');
    // производим замену текста
    var body_re = body.replace(text, '<p class="search">'+text+'</p>', 'gi');       
    // обновляем весь текст
    body.innerHTML = body_re;
}

search('Lorem');
```

Вообще как-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/dynRL/2/

Comment: Почему то не смогла добавить комментарий выше, где Вы прислали мне ссылку. Хотела поблагодарить. Спасибо большое. Разобралась.))

Comment: @Корделия всегда пожалуйста) Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @lampa, данный код разве не перезапишет все элементы, из-за чего слетят все события и т.д.?

Comment: @Oliver Patterson это всего лишь доработка скрипта ТС

Answer (score 1):

Если пользоваться библиотекой `jQuery`, то слово можно найти вот таким способом:

```
var $findedEl = $(':contein('+word+')');
```

Comment: хоть написали бы правильно [contains][1]


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/