# Как выделить определенные слова в тексте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив слов. Я хочу сделать чтобы эти слова на странице оборачивались в

`<div class="word">...</div>`

Но не совсем понимаю  как это сделать.

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: Скорее всего, этот вопрос уже обсуждался вот ткт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244608/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5

Answer (score 1):

Простое и "грязное" решение - замена разметки элемента-контейнера или `body`:

```
document.body.innerHTML = arrayOfWords.reduce(
  (rslt, word) => rslt.replace(new RegExp(word, 'gi'), '<div class="word">$&</div>')
, document.body.innerHTML);
```

Решение грязное потому что такая замена может сломать разметку, если в `arrayOfWords` окажется строка совпадающая с тегами, с атрибутами (включая не только имена, но и значения), или с содержимым `<style>` и `<script>`.
То есть, если и применять такой вариант (или подобные ему), то с большой осторожностью.

---

Подобные задачи, строго говоря, вообще должны решаться не изменением уже существующей разметки (как предполагает вопрос), которое в любом случае окажется "грязным" так или иначе - а генерацией элементов контента из набора данных (обычно для этого применяют реактивные библиотеки работающие с Shadow DOM, такие как [React](https://ru.reactjs.org/) и [Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/)).

Comment: Ну иногда текст может быть динамическим. Хотя, там такое решение не подойдёт. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919286/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, когда текст динамический, использование Shadow DOM библиотек с реактивным связыванием данных как раз и выгодно, из-за того что они берут на себя пересчет при вводе и перестраивание элементов ("умно" заменяя только модифицированные узлы DOM, и при этом кэшируя все что только можно). Конечно, подобную систему возможно и самостоятельно реализовать, но тогда процесс реализации будет все больше напоминать изобретение велосипеда :) То есть, принципы конечно те же самые остаются, элементы надо оборачивать... но самую сложную часть разумнее доверить надежному, оттерстированому инструменту.

Comment: Я ж дал ссылку на пример с поиском текста. Какое отношение к этому вообще имеет shadow dom?

Comment: @Qwertiy, отношение такое, что во второй части ответа упоминаются библиотеки работающие через Shadow DOM, и они являются наилучшим (с моей точки зрения) инструментом изменения DOM "на лету". Другими словами: _пример по ссылке безусловно хороший_, но такой код имхо не стоит писать в целях кроме образовательных - для решения реальных задач, будет разумнее взять готовый надежный инструмент, который абстрагирует их до уровня бизнес-логики (и именно на ней сконцентироваться, а не на создании инструментов). Это как при задаче "нарезать мясо" брать готовый нож, а не изготавливать его обтесывая камень

Comment: Но shadow dom - это кастомные элементы. Не понимаю, как это может соотноситься с поиском на странице. Или предлагается вообще от всех стандартных тегов отказаться и использовать только кастомные?

Comment: @Qwertiy, насколько я понимаю Shadow DOM, это просто фрагмент документа "вне" основного дерева, и он не обязывает использовать кастомные элементы: вызвав от любого стандартного элемента метод `attachShadow`, мы тем самым создадим ему shadow root который будет привязан к этому элементу (или к его ноду? вот в самой механике взаимосвязи, не уверен).

Comment: Прикольно. Видимо я ошибся. Но в таком случае, если мы хотим к произвольным элементам аттачить своё теневое дерево, то это будет конфликтовать с библиотеками, которые уже его используют. В общем, как всегда у всего свои плюсы и свои минусы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, будет конфликтовать, как и в случае одновременных изменений в обычный DOM из нескольких "конкурирующих" скриптов. Но я как раз предлагаю не самостоятельно создавать и работать с теневым DOM, а использовать библиотеки которые с ним работают (`attachShadow` упомянул только как пруф того что кастомные элементы не обязательны). Как использование реактивных библиотек связано с поиском - именно с поиском, никак. Оно связано с отображением результатов поиска, с генерацией элементов (подход альтернативный прямому внесению изменений в разметку документа через `innerHTML` и подобные ему).